# How are hybrid orbitals more energetically favorable than their components?

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

In the [orbital hybridization theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation), the $s$ and the $p$ orbitals are said to combine to form hybrid orbitals which are degenerate in energy.

1. How does the linear combination of the $s$ and $p$ orbitals result in (in carbon, for example) four degenerate orbitals?
2. Why is this configuration is more favorable than separate $s$ and $p$ orbitals?
3. Is the energy of the four hybrid orbitals between the energy of the non-hybrid $s$ and $p$ orbitals?
4. How would I go about verifying that this orbital configuration is more favorable?

Comment: Hello Charlie, welcome to Physics.SE! As it stands, the question is a bit broad, so you might consider splitting up the four questions in it.

Comment: The hybridization theory is just a hypothesis which worked well in explaining many observed compounds. However, it is not accurate and does have a lot of exceptions. The most accurate theory we have for bonding as of today is Molecular Orbital Theory.

Comment: It's just a theoretical model that happens to explain many things accurately, like bond angles. Orbitals are not real, tangible/physical things.

Comment: Even given that orbitals are theoretical models and not physical objects, I think the OP's questions are still reasonable. I would love to hear from some experts in the field.